# Lack of confidentiality for a letter of recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter

I was recently invited to write a letter of recommendation for a colleague applying for a tenure-track position at UCSD.  The email said:

> Although a candidate may request to see the contents of letters of evaluation in accordance with California law and University policy, your identity will be held in confidence. The material made available will exclude the letterhead, the signature block, and material below the signature block. Therefore, material that would identify you, particularly information about your relationship to the candidate, should be placed below the signature block. In any legal proceeding or other situation in which the source of confidential information is sought, the University does its utmost to protect the identity of such sources.

Firstly, how does this protect my identity, if the applicant knows whom he has invited to write letters?

Second, doesn't this policy lead to worse letters, without personal anecdotes and examples?

Third, the industry standard has been to allow applicants to waive their right to see the letter, and if they don't waive that right then the letter writer may refuse to write the letter.  Doesn't UCSD's policy remove this safeguard for letter-writers?

Comment: It is a matter for the California legislature, I think.

Comment: This seems more like a complaint than a question.  Also, there seems to be a misconception that the university has a choice.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask them separately.  Your first question is a factual one that depends on the circumstances that lead to a letter, and so probably needs more context.  The second one sounds like it might be a matter of opinion.  The third sounds like it could be perceived as a rant in disguise; see our [help/dont-ask].  We're not looking for questions that are a call to discussion.  I encourage you to phrase your questions neutrally.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, although job applicants, grad school applicants, and so on, can nominally "waive their right to see the letters", in most states this seems to be not enforceable, in the sense that it is not legally possible to genuinely waive this right.

When I've written letters, I construe peoples' waiving of "rights" to be an expression of intent, plus, an acknowledgement of the actual state of things. Yes, I've had people (misguidedly, in my opinion) *refuse* to waive these rights, which makes me wonder about their perception of things, and who's giving them advice.

And, yes, if someone is of the turn of mind to explicitly refuse to waive, I am much more guarded in my letter... ironically, usually because there are concommitant awkward issues as well.

And, yes, letter readers certainly understand that (in the U.S., in academic math, anyway) there is an expectation of at least pretending to not plan to ever demand to see the letters.

Yes, if we imagine that letter-writing should be fair and unprejudicial, then the issue of non-confidentiality might seem an unhelpful complication. However, decades ago, and, still in many scenarios, information is passed and decisions made in some sort of good-ol'-boy network rather than on a level playing field. That was, and continues to be, a bad thing, and needs pushing-back-against. (My own dept's faculty hiring has traditionally been a sort of star-chamber proceeding, and only this last year some of us have objected to it...)

So, yes, ... complications. :)

Comment: Regarding "unenforceability" --- does this apply to online platforms like "mathjobs"?  If a school downloads a letter from that site, are they under legal obligation to show that letter to the applicant if they request it?  How is removing the name enforceable, but not the rest of the letter?

Comment: @PaceNielsen, it's completely unclear to me... As you'd noted, removing the name is pretty worthless anyway, since people know who's writing letters for them. Given that known, finite, list, matching letter with author should not be difficult. I'd imagine that depts would fall back to some legally-justifiable defensive position if pressed... which may not include the best interests of anyone, but nevermind. I'm not a lawyer, but have seen enough of this stuff (in the U.S.) to see that it is muddled, and not as advertised, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, how does this protect my identity, if the applicant knows whom he has invited to write letters?

The candidate has asked several people to provide letters, so there is still a possibility he will have a hard time distinguishing the letters of the different writers. It is a weak level of anonymity, but it’s something.

Also, the policy is the same for letters solicited for promotion cases, in which case the letter writers are *not* (or not only) those suggested by the candidates. So while in your specific situation it’s not particularly useful, it is quite useful in other cases.

> Second, doesn't this policy lead to worse letters, without personal anecdotes and examples?

This seems impossible to answer. It might, or it might not, and even if it is, this policy exists for a reason, see below. (By the way, I still see plenty of letters with personal anecdotes and examples, and this is in a university that follows the same policy as UCSD.)

> Third, the industry standard has been to allow applicants to waive their right to see the letter, and if they don't waive that right then the letter writer may refuse to write the letter.

I’m not 100% sure about this but I believe that at one time there was a court ruling in California that held that an employer is not allowed to keep confidential documents about an employee that the employee cannot review. Allowing the employee to see an anonymized version of the letters resolved that legal issue. By the way, as far as I know the right to view your letters only applies if you were in fact hired, so candidates that were rejected will likely never get to see the letters on their case.

As for waiving the right to see the letter, I don’t know the details, but I suspect that this right to know what your employer knows about you was seen as so fundamental that it would be illegal for an employer to require the employee to waive it. And not requiring it but only “allowing” the employee to waive it would create a kind of coercive pressure that probably amounts to the same thing. So...

> Doesn't UCSD's policy remove this safeguard for letter-writers?

It does, and yet as I said this is done for legal reasons. In any case UCSD and its sister UC campuses that use the same policy somehow are still able to attract good faculty. So seemingly the policy seems to be working okay.

Comment: Does using an online system, to hold the letters for a short period of time, not resolve this issue?  The employer would never need to keep a copy of the letter.  The online site would act as a contract between the letter-writer and the asker.  If they don't agree to waive their right to view it, then the letter-writer can make a decision.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I don’t know, you’d have to ask a lawyer. We have quite a lot of those in California... I suspect the answer is no. But more to the point, the UC letters policy works well, so perhaps your premise that it needs to be reformed needs to be questioned. By the way, I remember being baffled about this policy in much the same way that you are in my first few years here and wondering why the system doesn’t break down in some catastrophic fashion. Eventually I realized that my bafflement notwithstanding, it just doesn’t.

Comment: Well, as a small counter-example to your "it works well" proposal, I'm refusing to submit my letter to UCSD.  That said, I wouldn't expect it to **catastrophically** break.  My personal objection to the policy, and my suggestions for possible changes, does not imply that it isn't **mostly** working.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I am not familiar with the details. I was told the reasoning is based on a court ruling about employers keeping (or maybe also having access to) documents about their employees that the employees can’t review. This is obviously problematic in various ways and was deemed to be not just problematic, but illegal. That’s all I know. And yes, I concede that as your example shows, the policy involves a trade off with some potential letter writers occasionally refusing to share useful information they have. But the alternative policy has other costs associated with it.

Comment: ... so overall I don’t see a clear argument to decide which policy is optimal. Personally I have no opinion about this issue.

Comment: Thanks, and reciprocally I agree that some confidential letters unjustly prejudice employers.  Thus, by not keeping a permanent record of the letters, there would be no paper trail for redress.  (As an aside: I started reading some of the legal implications for letters of recommendation.  I didn't know that even if you get a signed waiver to include a students' grade in the letter, you are also supposed to include a statement reminding the employer that they may not share that information without written consent from the students.  Gotta love FERPA.)

Answer (score 1):

Another different sort of answer, that may address one of the endless elephants parading through the various rooms of academe:

In the U.S., for example, if one has been asked to write a letter for a person who arguably/documentably has significant mental health issues, treated or not, the situation is tricky.

I note that over the years I've been the target of a few "grievance hearings" at my Univ, which, to my perception, amounted to students "with issues" deciding that I was the source of their problems... in some cases because I was the only faculty person willing to talk to them.

At a personal level, of course, this was very hurtful... but, um, was "educational" about what mental health issues can be.

It is important to not a-priori discriminate against people with mental health issues, of course. Um, and, how can we civilly and appropriately describe the potential dangers to other people? I don't know.

On a sappy/naive level, it was and is very disappointing that "being nice, being supportive, spending time, being encouraging" can still leave you as a target for threatened litigation.

(Again, I emphasize, this complication is *NOT* a reason to discriminate against people with mental health issues... it is just an issue that should be attended-to, if we all are to succeed collectively. And I do not know how to do it, myself.)

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution to this and similar problems: I routinely show my letters of recommendation to the recommendee. Even if they have waived their right to see the letter, I have not waived my right to show it to them.

There are occasional instances when this isn't the right thing to do. It may well not be in the case you ask about.